# UIBezierPath, Draw a curved view in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a curve that resembles the iPhone notch. So far, I have attempted to draw the curve, but I am not satisfied with the result.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
class CurveView: UIView {
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        addShape()
    }
    
    private var shapeLayer: CALayer?
    private func addShape() {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = createPath()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
        
        shapeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:0)
        shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 5
        shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        
        if let oldShapeLayer = self.shapeLayer {
            self.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
        } else {
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
        }
        self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
    }
    
    func createPath() -> CGPath {
        
        let height: CGFloat = 20
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let centerWidth = self.frame.width / 2
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - height * 4), y: 0))
        
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: height),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - 44), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - 105, y: height))
        
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + height * 4), y: 0),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: centerWidth + 105, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + 44), y: 0))
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
        path.close()
        
        return path.cgPath
    }
    
}
```

I would like the center to be a straight line instead of a circular shape. Additionally, the center should adjust dynamically based on the size of my content.

What I want:

[image]

Comment: You can use this app https://www.paintcodeapp.com to draw your shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to create that shape by using a `CGMutablePath` and a series of arcs with `.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: r)`.

Quick example:

```
class NotchView: UIView {

    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 24.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var notchRadius: CGFloat = 12.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var notchWidthPercent: CGFloat = 1.0 / 3.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var color: UIColor = .red { didSet { shapeLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor } }

    // this allows us to use the "base" layer as a shape layer
    //  instead of adding a sublayer
    lazy var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = self.layer as! CAShapeLayer
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        var pth = CGMutablePath()
        
        let w: CGFloat = bounds.width * (1.0 - notchWidthPercent) * 0.5
        
        var pt1: CGPoint = .zero
        var pt2: CGPoint = .zero

        pth = CGMutablePath()
        
        // start on left side, midY
        pt1 = .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY)
        
        pth.move(to: pt1)
        
        // top-left corner
        pt1 = .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY)
        pt2 = .init(x: w, y: bounds.minY)
        
        pth.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: cornerRadius)
        
        // top-left notch
        pt1 = pt2
        pt2.x += notchRadius
        pt2.y += notchRadius
        
        pth.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: notchRadius)

        // bottom-left notch
        pt1 = pt2
        pt2.x = bounds.maxX - (w + notchRadius)
        
        pth.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: notchRadius)

        // bottom-right notch
        pt1 = pt2
        pt2.x += notchRadius
        pt2.y -= notchRadius
        
        pth.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: notchRadius)

        // top-right notch
        pt1 = pt2
        pt2.x = bounds.maxX
        
        pth.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: notchRadius)

        // top-right corner
        pt1 = pt2
        pt2.y = bounds.maxY
        
        pth.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: cornerRadius)

        // bottom-right corner
        pt1 = pt2
        pt2.x = bounds.minX
        
        pth.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: cornerRadius)

        // bottom-left corner
        pt1 = pt2
        pt2.y = cornerRadius
        
        pth.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: cornerRadius)

        // close the path
        pth.closeSubpath()
        
        shapeLayer.path = pth

    }
    
}
```

and a demo controller:

```
class NotchVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        let notchView = NotchView()
        notchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(notchView)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            notchView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            notchView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            notchView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            notchView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
        ])

        // you can change these values from their defaults
        //  examples:
        //notchView.color = .blue
        //notchView.cornerRadius = 32
        //notchView.notchRadius = 8
        //notchView.notchWidthPercent = 0.6
    }
}
```

To get this output:

[image]

Comment: I added `stroke` but is not smooth, here is the code 

`shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor `
 ` shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3 `

Comment: @RashidLatif - you'll need to be a little more clear .. I added the 3-point stroke and it's not immediately obvious to me what you consider "not smooth."

Comment: I mean the edges are not smooth, there are some sharp edges at the corners of the view

Comment: @RashidLatif - again, you need to be a little more specific. Here's what I see when I add `.strokeColor` and `.lineWidth = 3`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwirc.png

Comment: As you can see in my screenshots there are sharp edges 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJbQt.png   https://i.stack.imgur.com/35ETF.png

Comment: the problem is solved with `self.clipsToBounds = false` 

Thank you so much 

Comment: @RashidLatif - `.clipsToBounds` defaults to `false` ...

Comment: Yes the default value is `false`, I did `check` by mistake on the xib